# Where can I see build minutes used?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know how many minutes of build time my organisation has used. Where is this information?

I found it once but it was so well hidden that I cannot for the life of me find it again. I have been through all of the "Organisation" settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It took me quite some time to find the information again but [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs-vsts?view=vsts) it is :)

In DevOps, browse to `Organization settings` > `Pipelines` > `Retention and parallel jobs` > `Parallel jobs` and have a look at the current value under the `Microsoft-hosted` section.

[image: Jobs]

Answer (score 3):

There's also a free extension that might help you, [Build Usage - See how many build minutes are being used by users, build definitions, team projects and more.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.BuildandTestUsage)

Comment: Just as a reference, that extension is planned on being [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2018/05/24/announcing-the-deprecation-of-a-number-of-guidance-and-tools/).  It was apparently challenging to synchronize the build usage with product billing.